# How optimize class member with constant private variables?

Tags: c++

I'm working on some embedded device libraries where space and performance optimization is critical.

Each of there devices need some constant calibration coefficients that :

- sometimes can be set at compile time
- sometimes need to be obtained dynamically by talking to the device

When the calibration coefficients can be set at compile time, the class member methods can be, in theory, greatly optimized as many of the computations are made with constants.

I would like to make a class design when I can instantiate the class in two manners :

- With the compile time coefficients and the optimized methods.
- Or with the dynamically determined coefficients and generic methods.

If it's help, as the class is a singleton, all my class's members can be declared static.

But I'm also curious how doing this with multiple instance where those with compile time constants use each one some specific optimized compiled methods.

Actually a use something like this :

```
struct CalibrationCoeff {
  uint8_t calA[12];
  uint16_t calB;
  double calC[10];
};

const CalibrationCoeff defaultCoeffs = { ... values ... };

class MyDevice {

 public:
 MyDevice(CalibrationCoeff calCoeff = defaultCoeffs) : calCoeff(calCoeff) { }

  double complexComputation(double input1, double input2);

private:
  const CalibrationCoeff calCoeff;
};
```

And I instantiate my class like this :

```
const CalibrationCoeff compileTimeCoeff = { ... values ...; }

MyDevice device(compileTimeCoeff);
```

But I'm face of two problems :

- I'm not sure that the compiler see that the class is declared just one time with constants so the methods can be optimized with there constants.
- I can't use this class with dynamic coefficients because if I declare the class with the default coefficients I can't change them later as they are `const`.

And if the coefficients are not declared `const` inside the class I'm not sure that the compiler will do optimization just by seeing that `compileTimeCoeff`is declared `const` (For some reason I need to instantiate the class at compile time).

Any ideas ? Even with all the members declared as `static` I don't see a solution.

Regards.

## Some precision after more in depth search :

When a class is defined in a separate module like device.h and device.cpp, the module is built separately. So it's impossible for the compiler to optimize class's methods using `const` or `constexpr` variables because the variable's values are don't known at compile time.

So it seems that the only solution to compile class methods with specific value optimization is to use **templates**.

But even if `constexpr` is now in the c++ standard it's seems that is still actually not allowed to use constexpr variables as template non-type parameter.

This functionnality [is proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r0.pdf) for the next standard but not currently allowed.

So if I understand well, to create some specific classes with optimized methods the only way is to use **macros**. But I loss type safety ....

Can someone confirm this to me or give me another idea ...

Comment: I've dropped this in [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ol6r4b), however, everythings seems to be optimized away. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Why are you "not sure" whether the compiler performs a particular optimization? Try it and see! If your platform & compiler aren't supported by the Godbolt explorer linked by @JVApen, you can still build your program and disassemble it to see.

Comment: I'm "not sure" because I don't know how to make code with trivial optimization. In this example  [Compiler explorer example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pLuxK2). The "complexComputation" don't change the input value with the given constants. I see that it is not optimized. I search for a way to be sure that the compiler will react in the same way that with `#define` constants.

Comment: Edit : The same [code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qWoKMI) with `#define` constants is optimized by GCC so my current design does not work at all. No optimization is done. I will give a try with static methods and static const.

Comment: @Prunkdump: `#define` can only work where `constexpr` works but not vice versa - a `constexpr`  function _can_ take runtime arguments. But since you already established that `constexpr`  didn't work for your case, it follows that the strictly weaker `#define` cannot possibly work either.

Comment: The main improvement of `constexpr` is type safety. `#define`s are more error prone because the values are not typed. But as I say it seems that actually class template don't accept constexpr as non-type parameter. And arrays and string are in reality used as references so the constant values inside the variables are not used for optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `const` ain't sufficient to get all of this optimized.
Luckily, we `constexpr` to force compile time optimization.

In the example below, I've added `constexpr` where needed (it might be you can do with a lot less `const` which is implicitly implied  at some places)

```
#include <cstdint>

struct CalibrationCoeff {
  int calA[2];
  int calB;
  double calC[2];
};

constexpr static const CalibrationCoeff defaultCoeffs = {{10, 20}, 30, {40.,50.}};

class MyDevice {

 public:
  constexpr MyDevice(CalibrationCoeff calCoeffArg = defaultCoeffs) : calCoeff(calCoeffArg) { }

  int complexComputation(int input);

private:
  const CalibrationCoeff calCoeff;
};

int MyDevice::complexComputation(int input) {

    return input * calCoeff.calA[1] - input * calCoeff.calA[0];
}


static const CalibrationCoeff compileTimeCoeff = {{1,2},30,{40.0,50.0}};
static MyDevice device(compileTimeCoeff);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int ret = device.complexComputation(argc);
   return ret;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UbU5VL)

Giving the following assembly:

```
MyDevice::complexComputation(int):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        imul    eax, esi
        imul    esi, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        sub     eax, esi
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

I've also added constexpr for the complexComputation (and const) + compileTimeCoeff and device. With this, I even get a better result for code size. There is no longer a requirement for the function pointer, as the function is now implicitly inline:

```
main:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/az_D3U)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help ! I need to investigate further to understand all the points and to check if I can design the class so that it can be also used with no constant coefficients. Maybe with templates... But I need to check that `constexpr` is part of the type and can be used in templates.

Comment: Constexpr on functions makes it compile time available, if the template parameters don't prevent it. Constexpr on a variable indicates: calculate this at compile time

Comment: After more investigation. Sadly this solution don't works when the class in defined in a separate module.

When the "class MyDevice" if defined in "device.h" and device methods defined in "device.cpp" the compiler built the module separately. So it does not know the used constants even if there are declared constexpr and can't make optimization.

Il put will put some precision in my question.